# HIVE: How to Parse / Ignore SLF4J Header in JSON Log Message

Tags: json, hadoop, log4j, hive

I am working on a Hive demo, and I want to perform and aggregation query on a file that contains JSON messages, prefaced by a log4j style message at the beginning of each log line:

```
20:49:07.962 [main] INFO com.example.application - {"DocId":"ABC","User":{"Id":1236,"Username":"larry1234","Name":"Larry","ShippingAddress":{"Address1":"789 Main St.","Address2":"","City":"Durham","State":"NC","PostalCode":"27713"},"Orders":[{"ItemId":1111,"OrderDate":"11/11/2012"},{"ItemId":2222,"OrderDate":"12/12/2012"}]}}
```

I have a large volume of such records, and am working on a Hive demo.  I am aware of the [Hive-JSON-Serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde).  But how do I tell Hive to ignore the log4j preamble?

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_json_object function to extract json data from the record and build from their on.  This blog can be of help. http://thornydev.blogspot.in/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html

Comment: The problem is, "20:49:07.962 [main] INFO com.example.application - " cant be parsed.  Also get_json_object is broken because it must parse the json body for each field you request, you could parse the json 20x times, when only 1 is needed.